# Explicit statement of Hecke's theorem on relationship of L-functions and modular form

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

I'm trying to read the "An elementary introduction to the Langlands program" by Gelbart and got stuck on page 11.

In this section the author states there is a connection between modular forms and "nice" L-functions(entire on some strip, satisfying functional equation, ...). And I'm confused on the explicit form of the connection:

1.is it true that for Riemann's zeta function the corresponding modular form is the theta function?

2.if we look at theorem 1(on pp.12) for Riemann's zeta function, $a_n=1$ for $n=1,...$. Thus $f(z)=\frac{exp(2\pi i z)}{1-exp(2\pi i z)}$, which should not be a modular form in any sense. what's wrong with the argument?

Comment: I know what's going on, we are working with $\zeta(2s)$, in which $a_n = 1$  only for $n$ being square.

Comment: Due to the $(cz+d)^{-1/2}$ terms $\theta(z)= \sum_n e^{2i \pi n^2 z}$ is automorphic not for $GL_2(Q)$ but "for a metapletic double cover", you should look instead at Eisenstein series (whose L-function is $\zeta(s)\zeta(s-2k+1)$) and cusp forms (for example $L(s,\psi)$ with $\psi $ a non-trivial Hecke character $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(13)^\times \to \Bbb{C}^*$ trivial on $\Bbb{Z}[i]^\times$) to make the correspondence clearer, see also Diamond & Shurman book on modular forms